# Verify the properties of the power set of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ be any set .Let $P(A)$ be the power set of $A$.Then which are correct?

- $P(A)=\emptyset $ for some $A$.
- $P(A)= $  is a finite set for some  $A$.
- $P(A)= $ is a countable set for some $A$.
- $P(A)=$  uncountable for some $A$.

  1. is false because $P(A)\neq \emptyset $ for any set at best it can be $\{\emptyset\}$.

2.true,Take $A=\{a,b\}$ then $P(A)$ is finite

3.True ,Take $A=\{a,b\}$ then $P(A)$ is finite and hence countable.

4.true take $A=\Bbb N$

But 3 is given as false.i am not getting it.Please help

Comment: Before anyone answers I think you should follow the following points, and try it yourself.

I think you are interpreting the terms wrongly.

In the second option, you have already checked that a power set can be finite, given a finite set.

So, the third option means countably infinite power set and not countably finite power set.

And you can indeed check that there cannot be a countably infinite power set. A power set can be finite or uncountably infinite. The proof relies on the assumed truth of the Continuum Hypothesis.

Comment: What are your "following" points

Comment: @user260674 The last sentence of your comment is nonsense; it is provable in ZF (even choice isn't necessary!) that no powerset is countable and infinite. The continuum hypothesis is completely irrelevant here. The continuum hypothesis says ["Every uncountable cardinal is $\ge$ the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis). Note: ZF proves that no infinite cardinal of [*countable cofinality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) can be a powerset's cardinality, but [that's it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I actually wanted to refer to the assertion that there is no transfinite cardinal between the cardinal of the set of positive integers and that of the set of real numbers. I believe that is what the Continuum Hypothesis is. That is the way I proved it. There can, of course be more proofs not using CH. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "countable" is used in two different ways:

- Sometimes it means "can be *injected* into $\mathbb{N}$". (This is what I'll mean by "countable" for the rest of this answer.) Under this definition, $\{a, b\}$ is countable.
- Other times it means "can be *bijected* to $\mathbb{N}$". (That is, countable *and infinite*.) Under this definition, $\{a, b\}$ is **not** countable.

The former definition is in my experience by far the most common - however, many texts still use the latter. I suspect that your book is using the latter definition.

So what (c) is really asking is: "Is there a set whose powerset is countable and infinite?" The answer is indeed "no". For the proof, here's a hint: if $P(A)$ is countable and infinite, show that $A$ is countable and infinite; this yields a contradiction (do you see why?).

*Technically, if you assume the Axiom of Choice, showing just "if $P(A)$ is countable and infinite then $A$ is infinite" is enough to get a contradiction; this implicitly uses the statement "every infinite set contains a countable infinite subset," which is not provable from ZF (= set theory without choice) alone. However, the argument using the hint I gave above doesn't use any choice.*

Comment: One question:is not every finite set countable

Comment: @S.Bandopadhaya It depends on who you talk to, that's the point of my answer! Some texts use "countable" to mean what I would call "countable *and infinite*"; others (most) don't. So you need to look at how your text (or class) has defined "countable." (Yes, this is very frustrating, but it happens from time to time. Another good example: depending who you talk to, [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) either do or don't need to have a multiplicative identity.)

Answer (score 0):

If a set is finite we do not say that it is countable, rather we say that the set is *atmost countable*. Thus, it is not correct to say that $P(A)$ is countable if $P(A)$ is finite.

The statement '$P(A)$ is countable set for some set $A$' is false. To see why, first note that any set $A$ is either at most countable or uncountable.

If $A$ is at most countable, then there are two cases, either $A$ is finite or $A$ is countable. If $A$ is finite, then $P(A)$ is also finite, in fact we have $|P(A)|=2^{|A|}$. Now, suppose that $A$ is countable. Since $A$ is countable, the sets $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality. But the set $P(\mathbb{N})$, sometimes denoted by $2^\mathbb{N}$, is uncountable, and thus $P(A)$ is also uncountable.

If $A$ is uncountable, then $P(A)$ cannot be countable. Therefore the statement 'P(A) is countable set for some set A' is false.

Comment: Actually, in my experience "countable" usually *does* include "finite." Obviously this depends on convention, but it's worth pointing out.